# Why doesn't checkmark appear before visited links?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

There are many examples of the following *before* pseudo technique.  But for whatever reason, I'm not seeing the checkmark in Safari and Chrome.  Anyone know what is wrong?

CSS

```
a:visited:before {
 content:  "\2713 ";
}
```

Webpage content

```
 <a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">is a link</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NG5KX/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling for `:visited` has been significantly curtailed to prevent security loopholes, [**see this this from mozilla**](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)

Indeed, `:visited` and `:link` items can [only be styled by color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (**SEC7115**)

Answer (score 1):

This is because it was almost remove (but some styles such as colors) to prevent security flaws. It was possible to read your whole browser history with.

A small script could easily create links and then check if it has been visited by looking at the style.

More explanation :

- http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/12/03/browser_history_sniffing/
- http://krebsonsecurity.com/2010/12/what-you-should-know-about-history-sniffing/